# NuGet: Highest possible version of dependencies down the dependency tree

Tags: .net, nuget

I am trying to upgrade some packages on NuGet in dotnet/C# so that I can resolve some security vulnerabilities from Microsoft Defender in Azure.

Here's an example:
Microsoft defender identifies that package A version 5.0.0.0 has some security vulnerabilities. This package is a dependency of package B, which is a dependency of package C, all the way to package G. Such that:

G -> F -> E -> D -> C -> B -> A.

Package G's latest and currently installed stable version is 1.0.0.0. However, following down the tree, package A's version range is (>=5.0.0.0) for package G's version. Meaning NuGet installs the lowest version, 5.0.0.0. I could specifically install an updated version of package A (6.0.0.0), but it's a requirement for us that we don't install the updated packages for packages down the tree - but only the top level packages (Package G in this case), which are installed in csproj files.

Here is the example csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Package G" Version="1.0.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Is there a way of specifying that NuGet installs the highest version down the dependency tree instead of the lowest?

I looked around but only found examples on use in the Nuget.config file but that didn't change the Nuget installation behaviour.